# spark-submit - Cannot import packages from environment submitted as --archive

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I have a conda virtual environment, and I tried to pack it and then ran the spark-submit code by passing it as an --archive argument.

But from the spark-submit code, I am unable to import the packages available in the conda pack (pyspark_venv.tar.gz), it gives me module not found error.

I am using an EMR cluster.

My spark-submit code looks like this:

```
spark-submit --archives pyspark_venv.tar.gz#environment app.py
```

It is from the app.py, I am unable to import the packages

Comment: Have you try to uncompress pyspark_venv.tar.gz ?

Comment: @Zabon - i did not extract,

Answer (score 2):

From the [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/python_packaging.html#using-conda), you should set `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` and `PYSPARK_PYTHON` environment variables before calling `spark-submit`.

```bash
conda pack -f -o pyspark_conda_env.tar.gz

export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python # Do not set in cluster modes.
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=./environment/bin/python
spark-submit --archives pyspark_conda_env.tar.gz#environment app.py
```